# Ng-grid does not render correctly when used within angular UI accordion

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

Ng-grid not appearing in accordion initially (ng-grid is expected to appear immediately below search criteria)

[image]

After resizing the browser page ng grid renders correctly (By hitting browser maximize/minimize button)

[image]

List of libraries being used:

```
<link href="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.0/css/bootstrap-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular-touch.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.18/angular-ui-router.js"></script>

<!-- grid v3.1.1  -->
<script src = "http://ui-grid.info/release/ui-grid.js" ></script>
```

```
<script src="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.0/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

I referred to this post but in vain - https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/issues/50

Comment: can you supply a working snippet?